# FFTW 3.3.3 Compiling with mingw: ./configure doesn't indicate any warning but make fails .‏

Tags: makefile, mingw, fftw

I run ./configure with options adviced in the [link](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html)

./configure didn't return any warning or error. After ./configure when I type "make" I am
getting error :

```
Error on line 490: expecting target : dependencies
```

If it helps , I can send the output of ./configure ,except that I don't see
anything that I can put here . 
If you advice me to send logs or any files please write me I am not sure
what to offer from my side.

The options I had used :

The one caused "Error on line 490:expecting tagret : dependencies error"

```
./configure --with-our-malloc16 --with-windows-f77-mangling --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-portable-binary --enable-sse2
```

Also if use options like below

```
./configure --with-our-malloc16 --with-windows-f77-mangling
```

I get :

```
Error on line 492: expecting target : dependencies
```

And finally if I use ./bootstrap.sh I am getting:

```
 Error on line 457: '~' is not a valid filename char
```

Comment: Please post the actual options that you are passing to `./configure`.

Comment: @PaulR I added the options I hope that will help me, thanks a lot